# Determining What Line Does in Awk

Tags: awk, gnu, gawk

I'm a very new beginner to awk.  I'm reading over a simple loop statement where by using the split() command I have defined the 'a' array before the beginning of the loop and the 'b' array in each iteration of the loop.

Can someone help me with the statement below?  I put it in to perspective since I know what the splits and for loop are doing.

```
split($2,a,":");
for(i=1,i<length(a),i++){
split(a[i],b," ")

#I don't know what the statement below this line does.
#It appears to be creating a multidimensional thing?


x[b[1]]=b[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a single dimension array. Let's say if you had a text file with one line like this:

```
1|age 10:fname john:lname smith|12345
```

- Assuming a delimiter of pipe symbol `|`, your $2 is going to be `age 10:fname john:lname smith`.
- Split that by colon `:` will give 3 items: `age 10`, `fname john` and `lname smith`
- `for` loops through these 3 items. It takes the first item `age 10`
- It is split that up by space. b[1] is now age, b[2] is now 10
- Array x['age'] is set to 10
- Similarly, x['lname'] is set to smith and x['fname'] is set to 'john'

Comment: You are most welcome, @Holmes. If you find one of the answers valuable, it would be prudent to mark it as accepted to bring closure to your question.

Comment: Thanks, just realized I could do that :D

Answer (score 0):

```
x[b[1]]=b[2]
```

It's not creating a multidementional array.

x is a array. it's assigning the value of array key b[z] to b[z]. z is a positive integer I just used here.